# Regex get everything between quotations including quotations using Rust

Tags: regex, rust, ffmpeg

I want to use regex to get the audio devices names from an ffmpeg -list_devices command as shown here: [ffmpeg list devices command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm6y8.png)

the devices will be different for everyone and I wanted to use the text generated from the command to list the output devices for the end user to see so I cant use the unique device name to list as its unlikely people will know their unique device names.

The problem I have is one of my devices
[dshow @ 0000028ff51c67c0] ""What U Hear" (Sound Blaster Audigy 5/Rx)" (audio)
has paranthesis in it will cause em to instead of getting the whole name get NULL and " (Sound Blaster Audigy 5/Rx)"

currently the regex I have is `".*?"` which works for all other device names.

I could change the name of the device in the registry but that would only solve the problem for myself.

Maybe a different way to output the devices with ffmpeg is possible but I am not aware of any.

I am using rust so if there are any solutions I would greatly appriciate them.

Comment: Please share a short program demonstrating the issue. Show the actual output and the desired output. Otherwise folks have to guess at what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to get the first parenthesis up until the last one. The `?` in your regex makes the dot-match non-greedy. You want it greedy so you can remove that:

- [`".*"`](https://regex101.com/r/IBI2OY/1)

[image]

Here is a good summary on greediness/laziness in regular expressions: https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortuantly I did not manage to get this to work though I have found a work around matching instead the start of devices '] "' and the end '" ('. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` character in `.*?` makes the `*` quantifier *non-greedy* which means that it will match as *few* characters as possible while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.  Quantifiers are greedy by default, matching as *many* characters as possible while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.

So, all you need to do is remove this modifier:

```
".*"
```

Here's an example showing that this works:

```
fn main() {
    let haystack = r#"[dshow @ 0000028ff51c67c0] ""What U Hear" (Sound Blaster Audigy 5/Rx)""#;

    let re = regex::Regex::new(r#"".*""#).unwrap();
    
    assert_eq!(
        r#"""What U Hear" (Sound Blaster Audigy 5/Rx)""#,
        re.find(haystack).unwrap().as_str()
    );
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=49368994f468b1da5a3954113b33f4ce))

---

Note also that regex for this case might be overkill. You can create your own matching function for this case quite easily, saving yourself a dependency on `regex`:

```
fn extract_device_name(line: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    match (line.find('"'), line.rfind('"')) {
        (Some(a), Some(b)) if a < b => Some(&line[(a+1)..b]),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ad8589012a98f64de9b93411ba6633c7))

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I greatly appriciate it. I posted an answer about how I addressed my issue instead, but I am very interested in your matching function as I will already have to do some similar logic with the strings. Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

Instead I have decided to just search for the start of the device names and the end of them using '`] "(.*?)" \((audio|video)\)`'

I can extend the regex to include the device type (audio or video) in the matches then just run some simple checks on the string to include it in my list of audio devices only.